# Select users whose last associated object was created less than x days before

Tags: sql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a Rails 4.2.7.1 which uses Postgres database and I need to write a feature for certain group of users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I need to select users from certain location who have exactly one payment and I also need to be able to pick users whose payment `created_at` attribute is exactly `x`

I tried

```
location.users
.without_deleted
.where(num_payments: 1)
.joins(:payments)
.where('payments.user_id = users.id').order('created_at 
DESC').where("payments.created_at < ?", Date.today).group('users.id')
```

but it did not give me expected results.

Thanks!

Comment: Lukasz, it's very ambiguous. With your query, we have no context of what is the relation b/w location and user, what is num_payments, what is without_deleted. Please add more details for us to help you. Answering based on assumptions will just lead to back-and-forth.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @kiddorails. `without_deleted` is not relevant to the scope of my question as it just selects users that have not been soft-deleted. `num_payments` in turn is a counter in `users` table.

Comment: `User.joins(:payments).where(location_id: location.id, num_payments: 1).where('payments.created_at < ?', Date.today)` ?

Comment: *"I also need to be able to pick users whose payment created_at attribute is exactly x"* -- Why are you using `<` for the `created_at` comparison, if you require the `created_at` to be **exactly** x?

Comment: @TomLord good point. I was just working on top of his code(where he is using `<`) and didn't remember **exactly** clause. I updated in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out guys. This was a typo. I think that the solution suggested by @kiddorailsis gonna work. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You should start from `User` since this is what you want at end, and take joins with `payments` since you want to query it along.

```
User.joins(:payments)
    .where(location_id: location.id, num_payments: 1)
    .where(payments: { created_at: Date.today })
```